# problem pagination with this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Limit must be a positive integer

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with my code please help me to correct my code please it does not work I am new to android programming

**PostAdapter**

```
package com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.Adapter;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.CommentsActivity;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.FollowersActivity;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.Fragment.PostDetailFragment;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.Fragment.ProfileFragment;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.Model.ForAllUser;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.Model.Post;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.Model.User;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.Notifications.Data;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.Notifications.Sender;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.Notifications.Token;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.R;
import com.developer.fireone.fingaoffice.VideoActivity;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.tylersuehr.socialtextview.SocialTextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;


public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;

    public Context mContext;
    public List<Post> mPost;
    public Activity activity;
    public FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    public RequestQueue requestQueue;
    public boolean notify = false;


    public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mPost, Activity activity) {

        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mPost = mPost;
        this.activity = activity;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_loading, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        if (viewHolder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {

            populateItemRows((ItemViewHolder) viewHolder, position);
        } else if (viewHolder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
            showLoadingView((LoadingViewHolder) viewHolder, position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPost == null ? 0 : mPost.size();
    }

    /**
     * The following method decides the type of ViewHolder to display in the RecyclerView
     *
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mPost.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView btn_play,image_profile, post_image, like, comment, save, more,certification_finga,share;
        public TextView username, fullname, likes, publisher, comments, txt_time, txt_date, finga_android;
        public SocialTextView description;
        public ImageView post_video;
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            certification_finga=itemView.findViewById(R.id.certifier_finga);
            finga_android=itemView.findViewById(R.id.finga_android);
            progressBar=itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            image_profile=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            share=itemView.findViewById(R.id.share);
            btn_play=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
            post_image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            post_video=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_video);
            like=itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
            comment=itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            save=itemView.findViewById(R.id.save);
            username=itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            fullname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
            likes=itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
            publisher=itemView.findViewById(R.id.publisher);
            description=itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            comments=itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
            more=itemView.findViewById(R.id.more);
            txt_date=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
            txt_time=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time);


        }
    }

    private class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ProgressBar progressBar;

        public LoadingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_loading);
        }
    }

    private void showLoadingView(LoadingViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        //ProgressBar would be displayed

    }

    private void populateItemRows(ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

       //...

    }

    //send Notification like...
    private void sendNotificaion(String receiver, final String username, final String msg) {

        DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
        requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        Query query = tokens.orderByKey().equalTo(receiver);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Token token = snapshot.getValue(Token.class);
                    Data dataComment = new Data(
                            firebaseUser.getUid(),
                            R.mipmap.logo4,
                            username+": "+msg,
                            "Le Yamo de xa ! ",
                            ""+receiver,
                            "LikeNotification");

                    Sender senderComment = new Sender(dataComment, token.getToken());
                    try {
                        JSONObject senderJsonObj = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(senderComment));
                        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", senderJsonObj,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                        Log.d("JSON_RESPONSE", "onResponse: "+response.toString());

                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.d("JSON_RESPONSE", "onResponse: "+error.toString());
                            }
                        }){
                            @Override
                            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                                Map<String,String> headers=new HashMap<>();
                                headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                                headers.put("Authorization","key=AAAAST1mR1g:APA91bFEgcbD3UGgdhByr7gEP2Zrc1o6Lg2yqAZfhsPKtY1jPaGmc5MKblGLn6kT0atmVlPo95xaGTpxxTn997Bm_X9mlJQ6gwlY7wGl-Z7HV9RuJA6CP2JgSd52jRLycDoL8l_ONklX");
                                return headers;
                            }
                        };

                        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void shareTextOnly(String description) {

        String shareBody = description+"\n"+"\n"+ "Ce post ete partager depuis 'Finga' le reseau Social Afro telechargeable ici: " +
                "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.developer.fireone.finga";

        Intent sIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Finga>> Subject Here");
        sIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
        mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sIntent,"Finga>> Share Via"));

    }

    private void ShareImageAndText(String description, Bitmap bitmap) {

        String shareBody = description +"\n"+ "\n"+"Ce post ete partager depuis 'Finga' le reseau Social Afro telechargeable ici: " +
                "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.developer.fireone.finga";
        Uri uri = saveImageToShare(bitmap);

        Intent sIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
        sIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
        sIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Finga>> Subject Here");
        sIntent.setType("image/png");
        mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sIntent,"Finga>> Share Via"));


    }

    private Uri saveImageToShare(Bitmap bitmap) {

        File imageFolder = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(),"images");
        Uri uri = null;

        try {
            imageFolder.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(imageFolder,"shared_image.png");

            FileOutputStream stream =new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90,stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext,"com.developer.fireone.finga.fileprovider",file);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return uri;
    }

    private void getComments(String postid, final TextView comments ){

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments").child(postid);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                comments.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.viewAll)+" "+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()+" "+mContext.getString(R.string.comments1));

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    // isliked
    private void isLiked(String postid, final ImageView imageView){

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Likes")
                .child(postid);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try{
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).exists()){
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);
                        imageView.setTag("liked");
                    }else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
                        imageView.setTag("like");
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "wait a moment please...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }


    private void addNotifications(String userid, String postid){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userid);

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("userid", firebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap.put("text", mContext.getString(R.string.strlikePost));
        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
        hashMap.put("ispost", true);
        hashMap.put("isseen", false);
        reference.push().setValue(hashMap);
    }

    private  void nrLikes(final TextView likes, String postid){
        DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes")
                .child(postid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                likes.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()+" yamo.");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }


    private void  publisherInfo(final ImageView image_profile,final ImageView certification_finga, final TextView username, final TextView fullname, final TextView publisher, final String userid){

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                final User user= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if(user.getCertifier()!=null && user.getCertifier().equals("certified")){

                    certification_finga.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }else{
                    certification_finga.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(image_profile);
                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                fullname.setText(user.getFullname());
                publisher.setText(user.getUsername());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void isSave(final String postid, final ImageView imageView){
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves")
                .child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.child(postid).exists()){
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_saved);
                    imageView.setTag("saved");
                }else{
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save_black);
                    imageView.setTag("save");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void editPost(final String postid){

        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.strEditPost);

        final EditText editText = new EditText(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        editText.setLayoutParams(lp);
        alertDialog.setView(editText);

        getText(postid, editText);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.strEdit, (dialogInterface, i) -> {

            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("description", editText.getText().toString());

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
                    .child(postid).updateChildren(hashMap);

        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.strCancel, (dialogInterface, i) -> dialogInterface.dismiss());

        alertDialog.show();

    }

    private void getText(String postid, final EditText editText) {

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
                .child(postid);

        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                editText.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getDescription());


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**MainFragment**

```
 private void initScrollListener() {
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

                if (!isLoading) {
                    if (linearLayoutManager != null && linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == postList.size() - 1) {
                        //bottom of list!
                        loadMore();
                        isLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void loadMore() {

        postList.add(null);
        postAdapter.notifyItemInserted(postList.size() - 1);


        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                postList.remove(postList.size() - 1);
                int scrollPosition = postList.size();
                postAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(scrollPosition);
                currentSize = scrollPosition;
                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
                reference.keepSynced(true);

                Query postQuery = reference.startAt(oldestPostId).limitToLast(currentSize*10);

                postQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        postList.clear();

                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                            Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                            for(String id:followingList){
                                oldestPostId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                                snapshot.getChildrenCount();

                                if(post.getPublisher()!=null && post.getPublisher().equals(id)){

                                    postList.add(post);
                                    indication.stopShimmer();
                                    indication.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    currentSize++;


                                }

                            }

                            if(post.getPublisher()!=null && post.getPublisher().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                                postList.add(post);
                                //stop shimmer
                                indication.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                indication.stopShimmer();

                            }

                        }

//                postAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(postList.size());
//                postAdapter.notifyItemChanged(postList.size());
                        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        isLoading=false;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                isLoading = false;
            }
        }, 2000);


    }


    }







    private void readsposts(){

            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
            reference.keepSynced(true);

             Query postQuery = reference.limitToLast(10);

            postQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                         postList.clear();

                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                        for(String id:followingList){

                            if(post.getPublisher()!=null && post.getPublisher().equals(id)){



                                postList.add(post);
                                indication.stopShimmer();
                                indication.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                            }

                        }

                        if(post.getPublisher()!=null && post.getPublisher().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                            postList.add(post);
                            //stop shimmer
                            indication.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            indication.stopShimmer();

                             }

                        }

//                postAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(postList.size());
//                postAdapter.notifyItemChanged(postList.size());
                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to correct your code.

Comment: Please study [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to effectively ask for help here. As it stands, there is way too much code, and not enough clarity on precisely what goes wrong when you run this code. After studying the first link, I also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as reducing the scope improves clarity, and increases the chances someone can help efficiently.

Comment: Could you show me the full stack trace of your `IndexOutOfBounds` error? Also, could you reply to me in the comments instead of editing my response so I could keep track of what you're saying? thanks!

Comment: Just as the error says, you should always check if the index that you want to remove falls within your list size range whenever you're using the method `.remove(...)` in any of your ArrayList. You should add a condition to check this. For example, `postList.remove(postList.size() - 1 > 0? postList.size() - 1 : 0);`. You should update every call you make with `.remove(..)` function to check if it's in the right range.

Answer (score 1):

The `limitToLast(...)` function in the line `Query postQuery = reference.startAt(oldestPostId).limitToLast(currentSize*10);` in your `loadMore()` function needs to be a *positive* integer as the exception says. So if your `currentSize` is 0, this exception is thrown.

So instead of `currentSize = scrollPosition;` you should replace it with:
`currentSize = scrollPosition == 0 ? 1 : scrollPosition;`